# After i pushed to heroku with "git push heroku" i get this error

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-api

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

and these logs messages

```html
2017-06-20T13:46:11.664248+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "
start"
2017-06-20T13:46:11.664249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.11.0
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665569+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665571+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665572+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node-web-server@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665574+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665574+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the node-web-server@1.0.0 start script 'node server.j
s'.
2017-06-20T13:46:11.665575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm instal
led.
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-web-serv
er package,
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668265+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668266+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this projec
t with:
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs node-web-server
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668268+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-web-server
2017-06-20T13:46:11.668268+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-20T13:46:11.672268+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-20T13:46:11.673433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-06-20T13:46:11.673435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-06-20T13:46:11.809096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-20T13:46:11.822443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-20T17:15:40.868366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret
-ridge-97436.herokuapp.com request_id=c9623bbb-fb23-4052-b118-006d91a1644d fwd="41.13.66.39" dyno= connect= service=
status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-20T17:15:42.397116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
host=secret-ridge-97436.herokuapp.com request_id=8471e291-6c09-4bd6-88f7-9bf4e5d05357 fwd="41.13.66.39" dyno= connect
= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-20T17:15:42.749308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
host=secret-ridge-97436.herokuapp.com request_id=7a132992-ca56-42e0-afcf-d16a14ea7861 fwd="41.13.66.39" dyno= connect
= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
muzij@muzij-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/Projects/node/Express/node-web-server$
```

Comment: looks as an error in server.js

Comment: i've check the server.js there are no errors there.

Comment: u can check my git : https://github.com/JackMj/node-course-2-web-server.git